# How do I convert this TimeDelta column to total minutes in pandas Datafram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

[image: See column here for visualisation]

I have tried the following without luck:

```
df['TimedSpentInZone'] = df.TimedSpentInZone.astype(int)

df['TimedSpentInZone'] = df['TimedSpentInZone'].dt.total_seconds() 

df['TimedSpentInZone'] = df['TimedSpentInZone'].dt.hours
```

(And also divided by 60 etc to get minutes. none of the above works.

Comment: please have a look at [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - if an answer solved you problem, give a thought about accepting/upvoting it.

Answer (score 4):

You can, and should convert to `Timedelta` type:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['TimedSpentInZone'])/pd.Timedelta('60s')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Its been a long time, but for future readers, this is what I did;

From the looks of it this column in the question is already a Timedelta type.
If thats your case, you don't need to convert it.

Just get

```py
df['TimeSpentInZone'].dt.seconds / 60
```

to get the minutes.

Comment: FWIW, I went into the pandas documentation and funny enough there is no minute but we have `second`, `hour` and `quarter`.
[Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html?highlight=dt#pandas.Series.dt)